# My husbands account is also showing my Bookmarks, how can I disable?

Tags: apple-id

All my bookmarks are also on my husbands user page, I would like to remove them and read one question as to sign out of my Apple ID when in his account but its asking me if I want to make a copy otherwise all my data will be removed from this mac but will still be available on my other devices .... I just daren’t risk losing everything on the mac either in my user page or his ... has anyone come across this problem and how did you solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using the same Apple ID for two different people, so ideally yes you should sign out of the Apple ID entirely and create a separate one.

If you still wish to use the same Apple ID, you can just disable Safari sync by opening System Preferences → iCloud and disabling Safari.

[image]

Comment: Well my husband doesnt have or need an Apple ID , he merely surfs the internet occasionally . Thanks for the reply , I can disable Safari sync of course  but thats going to affect my iPhone and iPad ..... ahh

Comment: @sally No, it will only disable it for the specific user on the specific device you disable it on. Your iOS devices and other Mac accounts will not be affected.